# Web Components, semantic markup and document outline

Tags: html, web-component, specifications, shadow-dom, semantic-markup

Let's say we're creating an app called foo. Our app will use a Web Component `app-foo` which creates a shadow root containing the following markup:

```
<app-foo>
    #shadow-root
       <main>
           ...
       </main>
</app-foo>
```

Of course, the user is not concerned with what's inside the shadow root of the Web Components they use, so they just write their document as they deem fit and use `app-foo` wherever they need it. This means the document could contain a `main` element, just like `app-foo`.

You might be aware that the html specs (see [html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)) tells us that

> A document must not have more than one `main` element that does not have the `hidden` attribute specified.

What does "document" really mean there? Do shadow roots, in some ways, count as their own encapsulated document, where rules such as these apply for each individual document-or-shadow-root (as they do share the [`DocumentOrShadowRoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot) API) or do these rules apply to the "flattened" document?

TLDR; would it be invalid according to the HTML specs to use a `main` element inside the shadow root of a Web Component given the page it's being used in also contains a `main`?

Comment: Was mijn antwoord verhelderend?

Answer (score 0):

> What does "document" really mean there?

The main `document`

> Do shadow roots, in some ways, count as their own encapsulated document, where rules such as these apply for each individual document-or-shadow-root (as they do share the DocumentOrShadowRoot API) or do these rules apply to the "flattened" document?

There is no flattened document, in this sense `shadowRoots` are more like content in IFrames

> would it be invalid according to the HTML specs to use a main element inside the shadow root of a Web Component given the page it's being used in also contains a main?

This is all about "semantics"

You quote:

> .

It says **must have** it does *NOT SAY* **can not have**

An informative quote from the MDN [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) documentation:

► **<> '    ' ;** ◄  ,     <>,    <2>,  , <> '   '       . '  .

#### Thus

`<main>` is there for assistive technologies like screen-readers.

And then we get to what some consider a Web Components "flaw".

Unless screen readers are written to "dive" into OPEN shadowRoots, they will only process `document` DOM. And ofcourse CLOSED shadowRoots can't be accessed.

It is up to the Component author how far to go with a11y

**Lots more reading to do:**

- https://www.24a11y.com/2019/web-components-and-the-aom/
- https://www.24a11y.com/2018/web-components-still-need-to-be-accessible/
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/styling-accessibility-a-web-components-approach-dc2aa8123eb2/